# WP All Import plugin image issues

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm using [wp all import plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/) to import all real estate properties in wordpress through xml. The issue is after importing, only the featured image is set to according posts. BUT the other images are only uploaded to media library NOT into the posts. It is not assigned to corresponding posts. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

To import the gallery of the photos you have to add the sortcode [gallery]
at the end of your description. BUT and this is very important be carefull about the names
each image has to have unique name else you have problems.

Comment: I have same issue in fields _property_slides. I created a question here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27873905/2074141

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?