# How to import multiple image?

Tags: php, xml, json, serialization, wordpress

Field image is accepting this type of format for multiple image import:

```
a:10:{i:0;
      a:1:{s:6:"imgurl";s:71:"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/image.jpg";}
      i:1;
      a:1:{s:6:"imgurl";s:71:"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/image.jpg";}
     };
```

I am trying to find a way to return a json_encode with the above output. 
In the process I can't figure out  `a:10:{}` when converted to array format.

```
$arr = array('a' => 10, // <-- I have a problem here what to use
           array( 'i' => 0, 'a' => 1, 
                          array('s' => [6, 'imgurl'], // <-- I have a problem here what to use
                                's' => (71,"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/image.jpg")
                               )
                         )
        );
```

Am I doing this correctly?

**Update:**

Sorry I can't response sooner. Since I'm studying how serialize and unserialize works.

A bit of history, I am using WP All Import- Import XML / CSV WordPress plugin to import XML data.

The WP custom post type `property` contain a field name _property_slider_image that store an image(s). Standard drag and drop of XML container to that field won't work. Not working as, it's not linking the downloaded images per property.

After checking the mysql database the field accept this type of synthax I mention above. I honestly do not know what it is. Since I only know is json_encode and json_decode. That is why my post mention json_encode.

Thanks to [Kiyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1488657/kiyan). He gave me a hint where to look.

Now I won't be manually mapping each image to each property record.

**Result:**

Here's my output after a weeks of research.

```
function sl_output_property_slider(){
    $image_url_list = array(); 
    foreach (func_get_args() as $n) {
        // get image name
        $img_name = get_image_name($n);
        // add directory location with the following format
        // http://localhost/dev_slrealestate/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/1478_Image.jpeg
        $imgurl = 'http://localhost/dev_site/wp-content/uploads/'. date('Y') .'/'. date('m') . '/' . $img_name;
        array_push($image_url_list, array('imgurl'=>$imgurl));
    }

    $serialized_data = serialize($image_url_list);
    printf($serialized_data);
}
```

where `function get_image_name($url)` - to return the image name only from original url string.

**Sample Usage - short code**

```
[sl_output_property_slider({Images[1]/Image[1]/ImageURL[1]},
    {Images[1]/Image[2]/ImageURL[1]},{Images[1]/Image[3]/ImageURL[1]},
    {Images[1]/Image[4]/ImageURL[1]},{Images[1]/Image[5]/ImageURL[1]},
    {Images[1]/Image[6]/ImageURL[1]},{Images[1]/Image[7]/ImageURL[1]},
    {Images[1]/Image[8]/ImageURL[1]},{Images[1]/Image[9]/ImageURL[1]},
    {Images[1]/Image[10]/ImageURL[1]}
 )
]
```

Comment: What is your question?! I don't get it, it's so unclear! Do you search for a input to get the output of the first code box ?!

Comment: As last resort I take a reverse Engineering style of solving. Your somehow correct. I checked the database where this table and field is located. The synthax I mention is how it is stored. In WP All Import- Import XML / CSV - Custom Field - you have two option to place the XML container. 1.] Serialize 2.] Mapping. Serialize is the best choice. But I wasted too much time already trying different combination to place the  `\ {Images[1]/Image[10]/ImageURL[1]}` for example to the `_property_slider` with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not a json string, you have to use unserialize function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 1):

As Kiyan stated, you're confusing between `json` and `serialize` formats.

The array representation you given can be created using:

```
$arr = array(
    array('imgurl' => 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/image.jpg'),
    array('imgurl' => 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/image.jpg'),
);

$serialized = serialize($arr);
```

Example:

```
echo $serialized;
```

Gives:

> a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:6:"imgurl";s:55:"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/image.jpg";}i:1;a:1:{s:6:"imgurl";s:55:"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/image.jpg";}}

Comment: yes, I realized that after Kiyan mention about  unserialize. I already figure out who to used the serialize function before reading your answer.

Comment: That's the most important thing :-).

Comment: It's kinda unusual to used `printf($serialized_data)` as return like instead of `return $serialized_data`

Comment: It's kinda unusual to not use standard serialization (xml, json, yml...) to communicate between several apps :-)